# This relative module was not found after Vuetify Upgrade

Tags: vuetify.js

After upgrading from Vuetify 2.3.11 to Vuetify 2.3.13 I got the following error

This relative module was not found:

- ../../../src/components/VContent/VContent.sass in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VContent/VContent.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question on the Vuetify Discord and quickly got an answer. Wanted to post it here for anyone looking for the answer:

delete the node_modules directory in your project
and run
`npm ci`.
npm leaves old files lying around sometimes

Thanks to Kael from the Vuetify Core Team for the answer.

Comment: Also fixed for me. Issue occurred when pulling an application update that included upgrading vuetify to `2.5.8` from `2.2.27`. Deleting node_modules + `npm ci` did the trick.